# Not able to get access token for Microsoft Graph API javascript ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, graph, outlook-addin, access-token

I'm trying to create an Outlook add-in for my Organization (Office ProPlus subscription). I am successfully able to hit the /me, /findMeetingTimes, /getSchedule and other APIs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-concept-overview).

I'd like to get a new access_token every time it expires, but am struggling to reach the token API to obtain new access_token using a refresh token from my javascript call.

I'm able to hit the API https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token over postman, and get a perfect response:

Response:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Contacts.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared Files.ReadWrite.All Mail.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite.Shared Mail.Send People.Read.All profile User.Read User.ReadWrite openid email",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFDNXVuYTBFVUZnVElGOEVsYXh0V2pUaGVqcWYwNDNiZF9RZjQ5a1NxQnMub25taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tIiwidXRpIjoiUWJ5NnNSRkcya3VtZFVLZUFFZlhBUSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsIndpZHMiOlsiNjJlOTAzOTQtNjlmNS00MjM3LTkxOTAtMDEyMTc3MTQ1ZTEwIl0sInhtc19zdCI6eyJzdWIiOiJMS2VIdEdZb1FPSFlrTjNvenAxeVp6Y1BmLWgzT2NiV2ZpWVBEOFpBYUNnIn0sInhtc190Y2R0IjoxNTQzMjM1Mzk3fQ.f8OtUmkpz88JXwrLEeFj1aDV6L6Pm1W6-zPdqHjNaCej8OV6v.......(rest of the token)........FQ9A2APQuErfSljCYFFbsDzh5pvYYtwbbTT4TqnUSczEND2yWmgEONmF4tZUXFoFz49q0Z69rWSb-iJ_C0mQ",
    "refresh_token": "OAQABAAAAAAC5una0EUFgTIF8ElaxtWjTqne9aI0dwA5LgpuS878-78FMJrAfgwgXMWiA5KC5WE2......(rest of the token)......XMpn34b0TKU74LdeGTo3lTS0VGlY1FzJ729QH0Nmcg5k86aOesnk2essqoMskUKOY1Wq8d6C75JVd385LzVBsOvjpRVzcZ26htbToV40U5wQ9R20ejpLiCgAnxFlDsS9pG-0huTPlGaeSZS5kYECrDpWapyv4TckEnXPWWGVOeZIdaf6HB41IhNJ6OYy_HFbDFmlu2TqGQhRadNB827B87cbcOdARZyHc-"
}
```

However when i try the exact same request in my javascript:

```
var data = "client_id=<client_id>&scope=user.read%20calendars.readWrite.shared%20mail.send&refresh_token=<refresh_token>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F&grant_type=refresh_token&client_secret=<client_secret>";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (responseText) {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(responseText);
        document.getElementById("startTime").innerHTML = "Success " + xhr.response; //Setting an add-in field to success, just as indicator
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("startTime").innerHTML = "Error " + xhr.response; //Setting an add-in field to success, just as indicator
    }
});

xhr.open("POST", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token"); 
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

xhr.send(data);
```

I get an empty response:

```
Error
```

If I try a xhr.responseXML instead, I get:

```
Error null
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a sample javascript/ajax call to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token API?

Stuck on this for quite some time, any help or suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

Could not find any help on the forums

Thanks and Cheers in advance!

Comment: Figured out it was a CORS problem, how would i go about it ? Right now I am serving my outlook add-in from my localhost.

Comment: Check if [AppDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomains) solves your issue.